# How to contribute to someone else's repository?

Tags: git, github

I have a friend who has a repository in his GitHub account. I want to contribute (pull/push) to the master branch (the only branch) on that repo directly.

How would I go about doing this directly on the command line using git?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since you specified that you want to push *directly* to your friend's repo, your friend needs to add you as a collaborator in the repo settings.

However, given your inexperience with `git`, it would be better to take the indirect approach: fork the repo and use pull requests to move your changes into the main repo.

Comment: This is the right answer since the OP specifies pushing to the repo *directly*, but given the OP's admitted inexperience with git, the indirect approach described by @Zepplock's answer is the better strategy.

Comment: Agreed. I should have added this.

Comment: Merged. Feel free to roll back.

Comment: If i want to directly make branch from my friend's repo how can i do that? How the process will work then?

Comment: You still need to have full access to your friends repo in order to this. Or you create the branch after forking the repo within your fork.

Answer (score 7):

I'm summing up everyone's answer.

1. `Fork` your friend's repository.
2. Fire up your terminal and type `git clone {URL}`.
3. Use this command to create a branch: `git checkout -b new_branch`.
4. Create a new remote for the upstream repo i.e. the link of original repo with the command: `git remote add upstream {URL}`
5. Do whatever changes you want in your local machine.
6. Fire up your terminal again and type `git add {file name}` or `git add .` if you want to add all files.
7. Then type a message `git commit -m "message"`
8. Create a branch: `git remote add upstream {URL of friend's repository that you have forked}`
9. For confirmation: `git remote -v`
10. `git push` Here you have to give your username and password.

Comment: the {URL} at no.4, you were referring to the friend's repository, right?

Comment: @Dids yes, add URL of original git repo

Comment: Step 8 ==> "fatal: remote upstream already exists". I THINK this is solved by changing the command to "git remote add origin URL" (i.e., "origin" instead of "upstream"). This worked for me, but only if I used the URL of my fork, rather than the URL of the original repo. I think that's what you must have meant by "{URL of friend's repository that you have forked}", but I find that description confusing. I would suggest "{URL of your fork}" would be clearer. Finally, does this step really "Create a branch"? That seems wrong (but I admit I'm speaking from ignorance). It's certainly confusing.

Comment: @Kevin you create a branch when you enter `git checkout -b new_branch`

Comment: @AshutoshDash, that makes sense. The branch is created in step 3. So step 8 is mis-labelled "Create a branch". I think this is just a matter of confusing wording in the instructions.

Answer (score 5):

The right way would be to **fork** his repository, do your work and then create a **pull request**. Then he could review it and decide to merge it into his work. Here's a good description: https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/index.html

Edit: added a link to github.

Answer (score 2):

> Agreeds with falk's answer above. Check if you are a collaborator, or
>   can he give you an access? if not follow the below steps

Go to your friends repo and fork his repo!!

On your forked repo of his copy the URL

[image]

Install git on your machine. Go to root directory on your terminal and follow the below steps

Do:

```
git clone URL
```

now do whatever edits in your cloned repo. Say you have modified a file, readMe.txt. Since you modified it on your repo!!

```
git add readMe.txt
```

Now you should commit the change

```
git commit -m "Dude, I have modified readMe.txt"
```

**Now push:**

you need to add your remote github repo to push changes in to your forked repository

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/myproject.git
```

To confirm see:

```
git remote -v
```

Now after confirming, you can push the code:

```
git push
```

**Git pull:**

> I am assuming your friend has not added you in the list of
>   contributors. Since you have made changes to some file, now you want to see those changes in your friends repo as well. So send him the pull request from your forked repo on
>   to his original repo!!

By the way this is the [awesome tutorial](http://readwrite.com/2013/10/02/github-for-beginners-part-2) I used when I started using Git.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are missing details.

[Github's docs](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo) directly answer this question and clearly say the original repo should be added as *another* remote so the PR can be pushed, i.e.

```
git remote add upstream <original_repo>
```

Your own fork on Github can now be pushed to as "origin" (or whatever you labelled it), but the original repo can be pushed to as "upstream" (or whatever label to differentiate it from your fork).