# How to make branch from friends repository?

Tags: git, github

I want to contribute to my friend's repository. **He has added me as a collaborator. How can i create a new branch from my friend's repo and contribute to it.** 
I have read other StackOverflow questions. They are suggesting to fork the repo and then work on it and create a pull request. For example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750228/how-to-contribute-to-someone-elses-repository)

But i want to directly make branch from friend's repo and contribute to it. What are the steps. I dont find any detailed answer. Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to clone the repository from your friends server/computer or where ever it is. This creates a local copy of the current state of the repository on your machine.

```
$ git clone <friends' repository url>
```

Then you can create and check out a new branch in your local repository:

```
$ git checkout -b myNewBranch
```

After applying changes, you have to stage the changed files using `git add` and commit them using `git commit`.

When you're finished making changes, you can use `git push` to push your new branch and the changes made to the remote repository. Be aware that your changes still only exist on your branch and are not merged in any other branch. If you want your changes to be visible in the `master` branch, for example, you have to open a pull request to merge the changes from your branch into the `master`.

It seems you did not read much documentation on basic git workflows. If you want to work with git, you should read some manuals, tutorials and documentation to deepen your understanding of what you're doing ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info) is a good start). Copy and Paste will only bring you this far and always is potentially dangerous if you do not know what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

1. Clone the repo
2. create new branch by below command:

   ```
   git checkout -b branch_name
   ```
3. do your commits,push and raise pull request for merge

From website, you can just select branch dropdown menu and write new branch name to create one, and then clone the repo.

Answer (score 1):

1. Clone the repo using the below git command

> git clone repositorypath

2. Create a new branch

> git checkout -b branchName

3. Proceed commiting

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15430009)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out ! I will add the steps and edit the answer .

Answer (score 1):

Never tried that, but I would image that you:

1. Clone the current master from your friends repo:

   `git clone https://github.com/githubtraining/hellogitworld.git`
2. Create a new branch:

   `git checkout -b feature_blah`
3. Push your branch to the remote (and enable tracking)

   `git push -u origin feature_blah`

Answer (score 0):

You might have received an email when your friend has added you as a collaborator. You have to accept it to get access.

Refer [this](https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/).

After you get access you can `git clone <repository path>` to clone to local and contribute.