# How to push the folder on the desktop on my mac to my friend's repository's branch on Github?

Tags: git, github, upload, push

I created a clone

first

Okay I will explain the problem from the scratch

I created stockPriceApp repo on my Github account

I already uploaded the folder having HTML and js files for the system

Up to now, I have the repo named stockPriceApp

my friend orders me to put the folder into the branch named limit-stocks of his repo named Ionic-GraphJS

---

Joey

I opened Terminal locating the folder named stockPriceApp.

on the desktop my mac book

I really want to push this to the branch of the repository on my GitHub account

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to contribute to someone else's repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750228/how-to-contribute-to-someone-elses-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+push+friend+repository

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to clone your friends repo to your local, then checkout to the branch you want to push the code to. Then drag and drop all your changes into the project repo. Commit your changes and push them.

```
git clone <url>
git checkout <branch>
# drag and drop files into the project repo
git add <all required files>
git commit -m "any message"
git push
```

PS: For doing the above you need to have contributor access to your friends repo.

Comment: can you tell me where I should drag and drop files into?

Comment: Hey @JoeyNamiki, into the repo you cloned on step 1.